# Configuring catalog items through manifest.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Using `spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-service-broker` we developed a `service broker`.
Initially we defined catalog items within `application.yml` file which gets bundled inside jar and this all works great.

Instead of bundling catalog items within jar file, we thought of supplying through `manifest.yml` file while pushing the service to `cloud foundry`. 
But unfortunately application is not getting the catalog items specified in `manigest.yml` file. Could you please let us know how do we supply catalog items through `manifest.yml` file?

I have copied my code snippet here.

**CatalogConfig.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "catalog")
@Component
public class CatalogConfig {
private List<ServiceDefinitionProxy> services;

public CatalogConfig() {
    super();
}

@Bean
Catalog catalog() {
    return new Catalog(services.stream().map(s -> s.unproxy())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

public CatalogConfig(List<ServiceDefinitionProxy> services) {
    super();
    this.services = services;
}

public List<ServiceDefinitionProxy> getServices() {
    return services;
}

public void setServices(List<ServiceDefinitionProxy> services) {
    this.services = services;
}

public ServiceDefinitionProxy findServiceDefinition(String serviceId) {
    return services.stream().filter(s -> s.getId().equals(serviceId))
            .findFirst().get();
}
}
```

**Manifest.yml**

```
---
applications:
- name: my-service-broker
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  host: my-service-broker
  path: target/my-service-broker-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  env: 
    SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: cloud
catalog:
    services:
      - id: f1478faa-d980-11e5-b5d2-0a1d41d68578
        name: api-marketpace
        description: API Marketplace
        bindable: true
        planUpdatable: true
        head-type: api
        tags:
          - api
          - Manage API Marketplace
        metadata:
          displayName: API Marketplace
          imageUrl: https://my-service-broker.cf.com/images/logo.PNG
          longDescription: API Marketplace.
          providerDisplayName: API Team
          documentationUrl: https://wikihub.com/display/ASC/Training
          supportUrl: https://wikihub.com/display/ASC/Training
        plans:
          - id: f1478faa-d980-11e5-b5d2-0a1d41d68579
            name: unlimited
            description: free
            metadata:
              costs:
                - amount:
                    usd: 0.00
                  unit: PER MONTH
              bullets:
                - Basic Unlimited
        dashboardClient:
          id: api-marketpace
          secret: secret
          redirectUrl: https://api.cf.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

That won't work.

The `manifest.yml` file is used exclusively by the [`cf` CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html) to provide options when pushing apps to CF. Deployed applications never see this file or any of its contents. In fact the CF platform itself never sees the file or its contents - it is purely processed by the CLI on the client side.

The `application.yml` file is used by [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yamlhttps://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml) and the contents are provided to the app via `@ConfigurationProperties` and other means.

These are two completely separate concepts and mechanisms, both of which happen to use the YAML data format.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your quickly reply.  Is there anyway we could send the catalog items as environment variable through manifest file.  If it is just a string i can manage to send that property to my config class through manifest file but as catalog items are list, i am not sure how do we send it as environment variable. Let me know if there is any possibility!

Comment: You can specify env vars to be set on the app using the "env" block in manifest.yml, like you are doing with the "SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: cloud" env var in your example above.

Comment: But how do we specify catalog items as environment variables? I think all environment variables are of type String but catalog items are list.

Comment: "But how do we specify catalog items as environment variables?" You can't do that easily because catalog metadata is a structured data graph and env vars must be strings. If you are intent on specifying catalog metadata declaratively you will need to do it in application.yml. You said above that works fine, why does that not meet your requirements?

Comment: i would like to externalize catalog items but not bundled war/jar. So, i thought of spefifying in manifest.yml file.